# How to deal with a question that includes the correct answer in the question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

This is a rather bizarre one, where an old question (2008) was asked that includes what turned out to be the answer.

Question: [Good way to use table alias in Update statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551/good-way-to-use-table-alias-in-update-statement)

Now I found this useful as it helped me with the syntax I needed and I'm sure it will help future users. If you look at the marked answer, it's barely a comment at best.

Obviously it was up to the user to mark the answer they found most useful, but in the current climate of things I would guess it would be marked as a low quality post and deleted.

Is there any recommended action to be taken on this or should it just be left as reference material that will probably help someone in the future, even though there's clear issues with the marked answer?

Comment: Sometimes the answer really is *That's the way to do it* though.

Comment: I guess, but I would add that as a comment or put more explanation if I was going to say that in an answer.

Comment: I once had occasion to post such an answer. The other answer with more explanation got accepted, I got the initial upvotes. It can go both ways. Trying to locate that answer is a little tricky, can't remember the context.

Comment: Found it: [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14836228)